# SkyDNS does not work with Kubernetes 1.1.2

Tags: docker, kubernetes, coreos, service-discovery, skydns

I installed successfully Kubernetes 1.1.2 on CoreOS alpha (877.1.0) will the service files as link https://gist.github.com/thanhson1085/5a005e92245cb2288dee

After that, I want to run SkyDNS AddOn for my Kubernetes as a Service Discovery. And I followed this guide: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/addons/dns

But it does not work:

```
core@coreos-1 ~/projects $ sudo kubectl exec busybox -- nslookup kubernetes.default.cluster.local
Server:    10.100.100.100
Address 1: 10.100.100.100

nslookup: can't resolve 'kubernetes.default.cluster.local'
error: error executing remote command: Error executing command in container: Error executing in Docker Container: 1
core@coreos-1 ~/projects $ sudo kubectl exec busybox -- nslookup kubernetes.default              
Server:    10.100.100.100
Address 1: 10.100.100.100

nslookup: can't resolve 'kubernetes.default'
error: error executing remote command: Error executing command in container: Error executing in Docker Container: 1
core@coreos-1 ~/projects $ sudo kubectl exec busybox -- nslookup kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
Server:    10.100.100.100
Address 1: 10.100.100.100

nslookup: can't resolve 'kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local'
error: error executing remote command: Error executing command in container: Error executing in Docker Container: 1
```

It works if i lookup global domain:

```
core@coreos-1 ~/projects $ sudo kubectl exec busybox -- nslookup google.com  
Server:    10.100.100.100
Address 1: 10.100.100.100

Name:      google.com
Address 1: 2404:6800:4003:c02::64 sc-in-x64.1e100.net
Address 2: 74.125.200.138 sa-in-f138.1e100.net
Address 3: 74.125.200.139 sa-in-f139.1e100.net
Address 4: 74.125.200.100 sa-in-f100.1e100.net
Address 5: 74.125.200.113 sa-in-f113.1e100.net
Address 6: 74.125.200.102 sa-in-f102.1e100.net
Address 7: 74.125.200.101 sa-in-f101.1e100.net
```

### LOGS:

```
core@coreos-1 ~/projects $ sudo docker logs k8s_skydns.ed0ae89c_kube-dns-v9-a5afs_kube-system_b45f88f2-9684-11e5-9f5a-04018a53d701_32d98a24
2015/11/29 10:47:00 skydns: falling back to default configuration, could not read from etcd: 100: Key not found (/skydns) [2]
2015/11/29 10:47:00 skydns: ready for queries on cluster.local. for tcp://0.0.0.0:53 [rcache 0]
2015/11/29 10:47:00 skydns: ready for queries on cluster.local. for udp://0.0.0.0:53 [rcache 0]
```

kube2sky logs:

```
Failed to list *api.Service: couldn't get version/kind; json parse error: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value
Failed to list *api.Endpoints: couldn't get version/kind; json parse error: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value
```

And the below is the information for my installation:

```
core@coreos-1 ~/projects $ sudo kubectl get endpoints -a --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME           ENDPOINTS                           AGE
default       frontend       10.100.21.7:80,10.100.21.9:80       1d
default       kubernetes     128.199.134.19:6443                 1d
default       redis-master   10.100.21.2:6379                    1d
default       redis-slave    10.100.21.5:6379,10.100.21.6:6379   1d
kube-system   kube-dns                                           51m
core@coreos-1 ~/projects $ sudo kubectl get pods -a --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                 READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
default       busybox              1/1       Running   0          51m
default       frontend-1w89q       1/1       Running   0          1d
default       frontend-w44qx       1/1       Running   0          1d
default       redis-master-qde8g   1/1       Running   0          1d
default       redis-slave-3m0t3    1/1       Running   0          1d
default       redis-slave-m6fc8    1/1       Running   0          1d
kube-system   kube-dns-v9-zrd22    3/4       Running   96         52m
core@coreos-1 ~/projects $ sudo kubectl get services -a --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME           CLUSTER_IP       EXTERNAL_IP   PORT(S)         SELECTOR            AGE
default       frontend       10.100.192.188   nodes         80/TCP          name=frontend       1d
default       kubernetes     10.100.0.1       <none>        443/TCP         <none>              1d
default       redis-master   10.100.180.191   <none>        6379/TCP        name=redis-master   1d
default       redis-slave    10.100.146.91    <none>        6379/TCP        name=redis-slave    1d
kube-system   kube-dns       10.100.100.100   <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP   k8s-app=kube-dns    52m
core@coreos-1 ~/projects $ sudo kubectl get rc -a --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     CONTROLLER     CONTAINER(S)   IMAGE(S)                                             SELECTOR                      REPLICAS   AGE
default       frontend       php-redis      gcr.io/google_samples/gb-frontend:v3                 name=frontend                 2          1d
default       redis-master   master         redis                                                name=redis-master             1          1d
default       redis-slave    worker         gcr.io/google_samples/gb-redisslave:v1               name=redis-slave              2          1d
kube-system   kube-dns-v9    etcd           gcr.io/google_containers/etcd:2.0.9                  k8s-app=kube-dns,version=v9   1          52m
                             kube2sky       gcr.io/google_containers/kube2sky:1.11                                             
                             skydns         gcr.io/google_containers/skydns:2015-10-13-8c72f8c                                 
                             healthz        gcr.io/google_containers/exechealthz:1.0
```

See Kubelet Service Status:

```
core@coreos-1 ~ $ sudo systemctl status kubelet
● kubelet.service - Kubernetes Kubelet
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2015-11-28 07:17:28 UTC; 52min ago
 Main PID: 27007 (kubelet)
   Memory: 2.9M
      CPU: 944ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/kubelet.service
           ├─27007 /opt/bin/kubelet --port=10250 --cluster-dns=10.100.100.100 --cluster-domain=cluster.local --hostname-override=coreos-1 --api-servers=http://127.0.0.1:8080 --logtostderr=true
           └─27018 journalctl -k -f

Nov 28 08:09:26 coreos-1 kubelet[27007]: E1128 08:09:26.690587   27007 fs.go:211] Stat fs failed. Error: no such file or directory
Nov 28 08:09:27 coreos-1 kubelet[27007]: E1128 08:09:27.689255   27007 fs.go:211] Stat fs failed. Error: no such file or directory
Nov 28 08:09:28 coreos-1 kubelet[27007]: E1128 08:09:28.696916   27007 fs.go:211] Stat fs failed. Error: no such file or directory
Nov 28 08:09:29 coreos-1 kubelet[27007]: E1128 08:09:29.697705   27007 fs.go:211] Stat fs failed. Error: no such file or directory
Nov 28 08:09:30 coreos-1 kubelet[27007]: E1128 08:09:30.691816   27007 fs.go:211] Stat fs failed. Error: no such file or directory
Nov 28 08:09:31 coreos-1 kubelet[27007]: E1128 08:09:31.684655   27007 fs.go:211] Stat fs failed. Error: no such file or directory
Nov 28 08:09:32 coreos-1 kubelet[27007]: I1128 08:09:32.008987   27007 manager.go:1769] pod "kube-dns-v9-zrd22_kube-system" container "skydns" is unhealthy (probe result: failure), it will be killed and re-created.
Nov 28 08:09:32 coreos-1 kubelet[27007]: E1128 08:09:32.708600   27007 fs.go:211] Stat fs failed. Error: no such file or directory
Nov 28 08:09:33 coreos-1 kubelet[27007]: E1128 08:09:33.708741   27007 fs.go:211] Stat fs failed. Error: no such file or directory
Nov 28 08:09:34 coreos-1 kubelet[27007]: E1128 08:09:34.685334   27007 fs.go:211] Stat fs failed. Error: no such file or directory
```

Please help me to fix it. 
And can I use Consul to place of SkyDNS in this case?

Comment: Start with the logs for kube2sky in the DNS pod.

Comment: @TimHockin, Many thanks for your comment. I found the solution from your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution from @Tim Hockin comment.

I got logs from kube2sky service:

```
Failed to list *api.Service: couldn't get version/kind; json parse error: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value
Failed to list *api.Endpoints: couldn't get version/kind; json parse error: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value
```

With this error, I just need to add:

```
- -kube_master_url=http://10.130.162.60:8080 # IP Kubernets Api Server
```

To `skydns-rc.yaml` file.

All the details about my service configuration files, please see: https://gist.github.com/thanhson1085/5a005e92245cb2288dee

After that, restart `dns` service containers. It works:

```
core@coreos-1 ~/projects $ sudo kubectl exec busybox -- nslookup kubernetes.default
Server:    10.100.100.100
Address 1: 10.100.100.100

Name:      kubernetes.default
Address 1: 10.100.0.1
```

Comment: You should not need to set this flag.  It suggests that you have not set up the master certificates and service accounts correctly.  see --tls-cert-file --tls-private-key-file --cert-dir --client-ca-file flags on apiserver

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it just a typo? Try `nslookup kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local` or `kubernetes.default`

Right now, you searched for **kubenetes** when it should be **kubernetes**

Hope it helps!

**UPDATE**:
It seems like you haven't configured the --cluster-dns, and --cluster-domain in your kubelet service.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I changed `kubenetes` to `kubernetes`, but the result is same. I updated my question. Do you have any link that share  how to install SkyDNS with kubernetes?

Comment: I did it `/opt/bin/kubelet --port=10250 --cluster-dns=10.100.100.100 --cluster-domain=cluster.local --hostname-override=coreos-1 --api-servers=http://127.0.0.1:8080 --logtostderr=true` but still not works